# Gitlab CI: Run a script to determine if a job should be run

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to run a script in the job rules if-block to determine if a job should run?

I'm currently getting a validation error:

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:my_job:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax

Attempt 1:

```
my_job:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && ./gitlab-scripts/is-unmerged-pr.sh
  ...
```

Attempt 2:

```
my_job:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $(shell gitlab-scripts/is-unmerged-pr.sh)
  ...
```

Attempt 3:

```
my_job:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && ./gitlab-scripts/is-unmerged-pr.sh'
  ...
```

---

Edit: goal

I'm trying to determine if a commit was the result of merging a pull request. I would like to run a job on merge request commits to a specific branch before merging, as well as commits on that branch that didn't originate from a merge request.

Comment: No, this isn't possible with `rules:` -- rules are evaulated by a custom parser -- it is not a shell interface and cannot run arbitrary code. However, you can probably get what you want another way. Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks @sytech. I'm trying to determine if a commit was the result of merging a pull request. I would like to run a job on merge request commits to a specific branch before merging, as well as commits on that branch that didn't originate from a merge request.